# Sumar dos o mas DaataFrame y hay columnas que se duplican

Tags: python

La operación que quiero realizar es:

[Los Data Frame a sumar están en este enlace](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YPvUVQpUpWDRYnED0CqKekxPYszUtgxX)

El código que ejecuto es en Python:

```
df_total_derivado = df_granos + df_mineria
```

El problema es que se duplican los nombres, y yo solo quiero sumar la columna Carga, manteniendo un DataFrame, no una serie.

El resultado que obtengo es:

[image: resultado]

Como puedo evitar esto, lo hice de una manera muy elemental con la función:

```
df_total_derivado = df_total_derivado.replace({"OLAVARRIAOLAVARRIA": 'OLAVARRIA', "CABACABA":'CABA',"LA CARLOTALA CARLOTA": 'LA CARLOTA'})
```

Pero es muy tedioso si se tratara de un DataFrame de muchos datos.

Muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar

Comment: el enlace a drive proporcionado requiere permisos de acceso

Comment: Disculpas, ya le di  permiso para abrir el link, gracias